# IMarketBillingService override gen error

Tags: android, overriding, in-app-billing

I don't know if this is for everyone, but updating Eclipse and cleaning my project resulted in a problem with IMarketBillingService where

```
@Override public android.os.IBinder asBinder()
```

It was asking for me to remove the @Override as well as in several other places. Just to help anyone who has the same problem I'm including the answer because the current answers didn't work for me.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Right click on your project
Click properties
Click "Java Compiler" on the left
Uncheck "Enable project specific settings"
Click "Configure Workspace Settings"
Set the JDK Compliance -> Compiler compliance level to 1.6
Click apply and clean your project. 
Should now work.

If it doesn't set more values to 1.6 until it does work.

Comment: Compiling Android with versions higher than 1.6 was not compatible.

Answer (score 1):

Not necessarily a good solution because while it might help here, it might just as well cause more errors in other parts of the program.

The only reliable solution I found was to remove the AIDL file, put the generated .java among the normal source files (in its proper folder, of course), modify it manually by removing the superfluous @Override pragmas. As both the AIDL and the generated file are stable, they won't change, losing the auto-generation is not a loss.

Comment: Does this point to a bug/issue with the AIDL tool under the latest version of ADT? Why is the @override keyword now included, and is its inclusion an error? (If you know)